# text input for version (1.1, 1.2, 3.0,..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that has a field for searching by version number :

```
        <label class="formLabel">Version</label>
        <html:text property="valueVersion" styleClass="value" tabindex="11"/>
        <br/>
```

Is there any other nice way to have a button to increase or decrease the version numbers instead of just the user enter manually ?
Thanks

Comment: How about a dropdown with the valid version numbers?

Comment: This doesn't look as HTML. Are you using a template engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case (format of version number `x.y`) you could also consider using an input element of type `number`:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" value="1.0" />
```

If the browser supports this input type (HTML5 feature), it will add spinner controls to increase and decrease the value. Have a look at this fiddle (i.e. in Chrome):
http://jsfiddle.net/N9Bn7/

Comment: Neither Firefox 26 nor Internet Explorer 11 seem to support it yet. And Chrome 32 uses the regional decimal separator (it looks like `1,0` in my computer). After all, a version number is not really a number :)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to keep it as an input text, dropdown is not a solution because the numbers could go up and up.